# ramda transducers with final R.sum

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, transducer

I'm trying to understand Ramda's transducers. Here's a slightly modified example from the docs:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const isOdd = (x) => x % 2 === 1;
const firstFiveOddTransducer = R.compose(R.filter(isOdd), R.take(5));
R.transduce(firstFiveOddTransducer, R.flip(R.append), [], R.range(0, 100)); //=> [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
```

But what if I want to sum the elements of the resulting array? The following (just adding `R.sum` into `R.compose`) doesn't work:

```
const firstFiveOddTransducer = R.compose(R.filter(isOdd), R.take(5), R.sum);
```

Comment: If you add `sum`, you're not building a *transducer* but a reduction (a *reducer* with an initial value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this,
just accumulate on top of an initial 0 value

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const isOdd = R.filter(n => n % 2);

const transducer = R.compose(isOdd);

const result = R.transduce(transducer, R.add, 0, list);

console.log(
  'result',
  result,
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Great! I tried to do that but didn't put initial value `0`.

Comment: Hey, this is an amazing idea! I just wanted to point out, that ramdas `filter` will already return a transducer, so the `compose` call is obsolete. Otherwise, this is absolutely genius.